# If $\mathbb{E}[f(Y) \mid X=x]=c$ then $\mathbb{E}[(f(Y)-c) \mathbb{1}_{x}(X)]=0$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, self-learning, conditional-expectation

I am unsure of the validity of this assertion. I would appreciate it if someone could corroborate it. Suppose we have an arbitrary function $f$ of a random variable $y$ and the expectation of such a function conditioned on another random variable $x$ is $c$: $\mathbb{E}[f(Y) \mid X=x]=c$. Using $\mathbb{1}_{x}(X)$ as the characteristic function, is the following statement correct?

$
\begin{align}
 &\mathbb{E}[f(Y) \mid X=x] &&= c \\
 &\mathbb{E}[f(Y) \mathbb{1}_{x}(X)] &&= c\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{x}(X)] \\
 &\mathbb{E}[(f(Y)-c) \mathbb{1}_{x}(X)] &&= 0 \\
\end{align}
$

- Why do the second and third inequalities follow, if at all?
- If the statement follows, does that imply we can express known conditional expectations as joint expectations?

Comment: what have you tried? The answer is trivial, just use the definition of $\mathbb{E}[f(Y)|X=x]$

Comment: @Masacroso Thank you for taking interest in my question. I have tried this: assuming $x$ and $y$ are discrete, we have $\mathbb{E}[f(y) \mid X=x]=\sum_{y \in Y}f(y)P(y\mid X=x)=\sum_{y \in Y}f(y)P(y, X=x)/p(X=x)=c$, however I am unsure of how to transform this expression into an expression using characteristic functions.

Comment: I strongly recommend using $Y$ as your random variable, instead of $y$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the recommendation. I will change it straight away in the question and the comment.

Comment: Assuming $X$ takes values in a discrete set $A$, you can use the law of total expectation: For a random variable $W$ we have $$E[W] = \sum_{a \in A} E[W|X=a]P[X=a]$$ So take $W=f(Y)1_{\{X=x^*\}}$.

Comment: @Michael Thank you very much, I am now working through the answer using your suggestion and Masacroso's answer. I might come back with some questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Z$ two arbitrary r.v., then we define $\mathbb{E}[Z|X=x]$ as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the measure defined by $\mu(B):=\mathbb{E}[Z\mathbf{1}_{\{X\in B\}}]$ respect to the measure $P_X$, that is, by definition we have that

$$
\mathbb{E}[Z\mathbf{1}_{\{X\in B\}}]=\int_{B}\mathbb{E}[Z|X=t]P_X(dt)\tag1
$$

Then if $\mathbb{E}[f(Y)|X=x_0]=c$ for some $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ from (1) we have that

$$
\mathbb{E}[f(Y)\mathbf{1}_{\{X=x_0\}}]=c\Pr [X=x_0]=c\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X=x_0\}}]\\
\therefore\quad 0=\mathbb{E}[f(Y)\mathbf{1}_{\{X=x_0\}}]-c\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X=x_0\}}]=\mathbb{E}[(f(Y)-c)\mathbf{1}_{\{X=x_0\}}]
$$

∎

---

If you didn't see measure theory then the question only makes sense if we assume that the event $\{X=x_0\}$ have non-zero probability. In this case the above reduces to

$$
\mathbb{E}[f(Y)\mathbf{1}_{\{X=x_0\}}]=\mathbb{E}[f(Y)|X=x_0]\Pr [X=x_0]=c \Pr [X=x_0]=c\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X=x_0\}}]
$$

where the result follows again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try to understand the proof and will get back to you if I have any questions, if that is ok. Unfortunately, I don't know measure theory, but if I understand properly, (1) corresponds to the law of total expectation as suggested in Michael's comment?

Comment: And second, when you take the expectation $\mathbb{E}[f(Y)\mathbb{1}_{\{X=x_{0}\}}]$, is that with respect to the distribution of $Y$? What about the expectation $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{1}_{\{X=x_{0}\}}]$? Is that with respect to the distribution of $X$? If that is the case, why is it valid to combine them into $\mathbb{E}[(f(Y)-c)\mathbb{1}_{\{X=x_{0}\}}]$? Apologies if this is a too obvious question.

Comment: @Sergio as said (1) is the definition of $\mathbb{E}[f(Y)|X=t]$ for every $t$, but it can be understood as a measure-theoretic version of the law of total expectation. For your second question: any expectation is taken against the underlying probability measure, that is the expectation of the random variable $Z$ is defined by $\mathbb{E}[Z]:=\int_{\Omega }Z(\omega )P(d\omega )$. If $Z$ is an indicator function then it is the same than the probability of the event, that is $\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{A}]=\Pr [A]$

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand properly, the answer to the second question of the original post is affirmative. That is, we can express known conditional expectations as expectations over joint distributions. In this case, we can express the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[f(Y)\mid X=x]=c$, which is taken over $p(Y\mid X=x), as $\mathbb{E}[(f(Y)-c)\mathbb{1}_{X=x_{0}}]=0$ which is taken over $p(Y, X)$.

Comment: I am sorry, I just realized my previous comment had a compilation error, what I meant,  written differently, is that the following implication is true: $\mathbb{E}[f(Y)\mid X=x]=\sum_{y\in Y}f(y)p(y\mid X=x)=c$ implies $\mathbb{E}[(f(Y)-c)\mathbb{1}_{X=x_{0}}]=\sum_{y\in Y}\sum_{x\in X}(f(y)-c)\mathbb{1}_{X=x}p(y, x)=0$.

Comment: @Sergio, yes, what is in your last comment holds as far $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables